# Jquery function that performs css change if image isnt loaded

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to make a function whereby if an image fails to load, my image-holder element removes padding.

```js
$("img").error(function(){
        $(this).css({padding-right:"0px"});
});
```

```css
.image-holder {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  top: -4px;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-title">
              <div class="image-holder"><img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/arianagrande/images/7/70/Example.png/revision/latest?cb=20160301231046" alt="">
              </div>




              <div class="cfp-heading">
                <p class="cfp-title">Journal Of Network Theory In Finance</p>


                <p class="cfp-subtitle">Call for papers</p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Above is the code that I have made to try and get this to work however it keeps on throwing errors left right and centre. All I'm trying to do is...

If the image fails to load, remove the padding-right (or add padding-right: 0px;). Help will be much appreciated

Comment: You are missing `"`s around `padding-right`. Fix that and your code works. `$(this).css({ "padding-right" : "0px" });`

Comment: your css() syntax is wrong. read more here -> http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code working for me fine:

```
$(function(){
    $("img").error(function(){
        $(this).parent(".image-holder").css({"padding-right":"0px"});
    });
})
```

Comment: @MattWallis, if it is work for you please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).css("padding-right","0");
```

Comment: Please explain your code. We want to *teach*, not train copy-paste.

Comment: This is the right syntax to use for css rule in Jquery.